# Gallery(Horizontal ListView) inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, gallery

Ok i wasted 1 day of my life i think now is the time to ask for help :D
I have a listview that has an image text ..etc (custom view) and one of its
elements is a Gallery. (Aka horizontal listview)
Gallery also is a custom view.
SO.. here is the problem:
I call the adaptor to set the custom view in the listview.Ok for now.
Inside the listview adaptor i call the Gallery adaptor.Ok for now.
Everything render out as it should be with a very nice complex interface.
Now the problem
When i scroll the Gallery the data change to what the data should have been if i scrolled the gallery of the last listview row rendered.(Hope you get me here)
Ex.gallery in first listview has photos of the sea.
   gallery in 2nd listview has photos of a building.

If i scroll the first gallery the photos change from "sea" to building".

Meaning ... each time the listview adapter's getView is called i feed the galleryadapter with data

```
gal1.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter(CON,PASS[position]));
```

What i'm thinking as a possible solution is :

- Hardcore , preload all the data in the custom Gallery of each listview.
- Figure a way that when i scroll the Gallery element within a listview , the gallery adapter to be aware of the index of listbox and load the correct data.

I think the second solution is more elegant,and more difficult but considering that if i go for the 1st solution there will be >40 views loaded at all times so no biggy.

So.. I;m asking for your help.Is there a 3rd , 4rth .. way?Is anyone of my suggestions even possible?If so please point a way of implement to code.

Keed in mind that i want  to be able to do multiple scrollings at any given moment.
So i think that my 2nd suggestiong might have some problems there.

Comment: Hello, am stucked with same kind of problem. could you please help me, how did you solve this problem.? Thanks in Advance.!!

Comment: @DanielNyamasyo because this was asked on 2010.

Comment: Sorry i never looked the date. Also, i was using gallery but never gave me the best results which i was after

Answer (score 0):

Try using same gallery adapter for all list items and in getView of list adapter just change the data for gallery adapter.

After setting the data in getView just notify gallery adapter.

out side getView(maybe in constructor of list adapter)

```
GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter=new GalleryAdapter();
```

in getView

```
galleryAdapter.setData(CON,PASS[position]);
gal1.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
```